# Sorting an ArrayObject in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, append

I get the following error with this code -

> Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array.

```
$array1 = new ArrayObject();

$array1->append("50");
$array1->append("30");
$array1->append("60");

sort($array1); // Should sort to 30, 50, 60.
```

Can anyone create a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `ArrayObject->asort()` ?  http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.asort.php

Answer (score 2):

`sort()` only works on arrays. `ArrayObject` is an object and not an array.

Use the asort method instead ( `$array1->asort();` )

Answer (score 1):

#### Instead, you need to try this way:

```
$array1->asort();
```

#### See [`arrayobject.asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.asort.php) for more info!

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this issue because you are trying to sort an object. Despite its name, `ArrayObject` is an object not an array (see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)).

Your options are:

```
$array1 = new ArrayObject();

$array1->append("50");
$array1->append("30");
$array1->append("60");

$array1->asort();
```

or by using just an array

```
$array1 = array();

$array1[] = "50";
$array1[] = "30";
$array1[] = "60";

sort($array1);
```

You were effectively trying to use a procedural function on an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the `sort` function, you have to change the way you create your array to the following:

```
$array1 = array();
$array1 = array_push(array1, "50");
$array1 = array_push(array1, "30");
$array1 = array_push(array1, "60");
sort(array1);
```

Or even simpler:

```
$array1 = array("50","30","60");
sort(array1);
```